# Is there a Python package that will help me find a group with parallel trends that I can then use to perform difference in difference analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, python, analysis

I want to use the causal inference technique, difference in differences, to estimate the impact of a feature launch. Unfortunately, the cohort of customers that I was hoping to use as the "control" group does not meet the parallel trends assumption. I was wondering if there is a package that will identify a a cohort of customers that does meet the parallel trends assumption?